# Conflicts between SWC skin and Spark drawing API

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, skin, swc

I have a project where we are trying to skin Spark components from a third party library that are built up from the drawing API primitives.  Our first attempt involved creating a Flex skin  (SWC) in Illustrator/Flash and applying that skin to the Spark components via CSS.  We found that even with only a single instance of one of the components skinned in this way on stage, the application was brought to it's knees.  For example, it failed to respond in repaint scenarios in a timely manner, and exhibited all the symptoms of being hung.

Our next approach will be to recreate the same skin artifacts in MXML  classes that are in turn associated with the third-party components.  Although the complexity of some of the skins leads me to believe that we might not avoid performance problems with this approach either.

My question is the following: Is there a correct or recommended way to apply either a SWC or  based skin to a component that is built up from the Spark drawing API to begin with?   Even as I ask the question I recognize that the  approach means using the Spark drawing API in two places and will probably have unexpected consequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had good luck building the skins using MXML skin classes that inherit from s:Skin in terms of rendering performance.  The recommended method (from Adobe) is to start by copying an existing skin file from the SDK and modifying the MXML to suit your needs.  Regarding drawing, FXG works very well for defining how you want the skin to be drawn.  FXG is XML based, so you don't need to write ActionScript to do your drawing, like we used to do for Flex 3 programmatic skins.  You can also create skins using Adobe Catalyst.  I have not used Catalyst, so I can't speak to its effectiveness, but many people seem to like it.  Hope that helps.